# Display uploaded file name of file input in paragraph

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-form

Hi i am using useForm in my form. I want to display filename from file input i above input in `fileName`. How can i extract file name and display when file is uploaded by user. This is my input:

```
<div className="w-full flex flex-row items-center justify-between border p-4">
              <div>
                <p>CV</p>
                <p className="text-gray">{fileName}</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label
                  className="border py-[10px] px-6 border-black text-[13px] font-medium cursor-pointer
            "
                >
                  UPLOAD
                  <input {...register("cv")} placeholder="upload" type="file" />
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So here are the docs for future references to your problem.
https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#the-file-input-tag

And here is the working example of your problem solved.
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-currying-wkzhkk?file=/src/App.js

P.S.
Please cast a vote if my answer helped you. Thank you.